# AWS Beanstalk running webapp with a perl script

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, amazon-web-services

I have set up a Beanstalk application and everything is running fine except I use a perl script to bring in some NTP times from some severs and it seems to not be executing it.

I have run this on my normal hosting services fine and I had to set some permissions because I was get a 500 error but with the AWS app I don't get any error at all i just get NAN.

Its running a tomcat instance.

Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

```
function ntpNewTime() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', '/cgi-bin/server.pl', true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(
        'Content-Type',
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

That is the function I am using.

Comment: yes sorry, it isnt that on the server I just typed that becuase I was trying it in a different location. But thanks

Comment: I found it has something to do with the cgiPathPrefix in web.xml but I dont know how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to test the service basically

```
$.ajax( {
          url: '/url/to/post/to',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'html',
          data: $('form#form_id').formSerialize(),
          complete: jsFunctionToCallBack
        }
      );
```

[cgiPathPrefix - The CGI search path will start at the web application root directory + File.separator + this prefix. The default cgiPathPrefix is WEB-INF/cgi](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html)

if your service is reachable with "/cgi-bin/server.pl" i think it is not a cgiPathPrefix issue..

[XMLHttpRequest - maybe this can help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

futhermore you can press F12 in your Fav-Browser to take a look at the ajax call.. if the ajax call is done with status code - server.pl is not working properly